# Jest vanilla JavaScript JSDOM refresh fails, 2nd test breaks after switching beforeAll to beforeEach

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, jsdom

I've made a simple test to check if the background colour changes

### Tests

```js
/**
* @jest-environment jsdom
*/

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const html = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../index.html'), 'utf8');
describe('Testing script.js', () => {
    let js
    beforeEach(()=>{
        document.documentElement.innerHTML = html.toString();
        js = require('../script');
    })
    afterEach(() => {
        document.documentElement.innerHTML = '';
    });
    test('Button click changes output content', () => {
        const myButton1 = document.getElementById('button-test1')
        const output = document.getElementById('output')
        const outputBefore = output.textContent
        myButton1.click()
        const outputAfter = output.textContent
        expect(outputBefore).not.toBe(outputAfter)
    });
    test('changes background colour', () => {
        const myButton2 = document.getElementById('button-test2')
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
        const bodyBefore = document.body.style.backgroundColor
        console.log(bodyBefore)
        myButton2.click()
        const bodyAfter = document.body.style.backgroundColor
        console.log(bodyAfter)
        expect(bodyBefore).not.toBe(bodyAfter)
    });

});
```

### Code

```js
const myButton1 = document.getElementById('button-test1')
const myButton2 = document.getElementById('button-test2')

myButton1.addEventListener('click', () => clickEvent1())
myButton2.addEventListener('click', () => clickEvent2())

function clickEvent1() {
    console.log("clickEvent1")
    const element = document.getElementById('output')
    if (element.textContent === "") element.textContent = "Hello World"
}

function clickEvent2() {
    console.log("clickEvent2")
    if (document.body.style.backgroundColor != 'red') document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
}
```

### Outcome

the 2nd test fails, but when run in isolation the test works fine. At first I thought this was because the same button was being clicked twice but these are seperate elements. I don't think there is an issue with the tests themselves, I can't work it out.

#### what I've tried:

I tried beforeEach/afterEach() to teardown the html, hoping to 'reset' the JSDOM between tests.

### What I've tried

- Changing the order of the tests: the 2nd test always breaks
- If I remove the first test, **it works**
- If I remove beforeEach and afterEach, returning to beforeAll **it works**

This makes no sense to me, and breaks my understanding of how Jest works.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**

The click event in the second test is not firing.

**Explanation of Behavior**

When Jest loads a module via the require function, the module is cached in a registry and executed. As such, the require('../script') line before the second test is not loading or executing the script since the module already exists in the registry. This means that when you reset the DOM before the second test, none of the event handlers that were initially registered will be attached to the new elements in the new DOM.

There are two basic solutions for your issue.

1. Reset modules in between tests. This will allow the require('../script') line to load and execute the module independently for each test.

Jest Documentation:
[jest.resetModules()](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestresetmodules)

In your example code above, one potential solution is to remove the afterEach code block and update the beforeEach code block.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = html.toString();
    
    // Reset module registry
    jest.resetModules();

    js = require('../script');
});
```

2. Don't reset the DOM in between tests. This will allow you to work with a single instance of the DOM that persists between tests, and all event handlers that were applied when the module was first loaded and executed will remain in effect for your elements.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need afterEach, that is causing the problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).